# How to add images to the coverflow dynamically and update coverflow view?

Tags: ipad, coverflow

I've implemented OpenFlow library for my iPad application. http://apparentlogic.com/openflow/ 
After setting the initial view, I'm adding the cover images dynamically to the coverflow view. The coverflow view is getting updated. But my problem is i want to show the same cover which is recently added to the cover.

Comment: ok..see..initially i'm showing 10 images on coverflow. Now I have set a button to import image on that same view. When that image is imported and added to the coverflow, I want the coverflow should be scrolled to the  recently added image. That is..if the coverflow was showing 3rd image..now it should show me the 11th image.

Comment: I have found this https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel library...actually answer to my question. Its superb!!